# Struggling to make an accessible data table with clickable rows!

Tags: design-patterns, accessibility, data-tables, code

We're currently working on making our data table accessible. Our main concern is the whole clickable row that triggers a side sheet. The entire row is clickable, and a part of its content may be copied and pasted by the user. Because the row is clickable, the user has difficulty copying and pasting the content, and for the keyboard user it's not possible to focus.

[image]

Do you have any ideas on how we could solve this problem while retaining the clickable rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a copy icon/button next to whatever information needs to be copied by the user. Be wary of click size as you need it to be big enough to prevent any accidental row clicks.